# How to make spline ik work like HumanIK's spine in Maya?

Tags: maya

I'm trying to setup Spline Ik work like HumanIk's spine, but I can't control the bending of the curve of Spline Ik. Here is the picture:

Fig.1. Compare HumanIk vs SplineIk

[image: HumanIk and SplineIk]

Fig.2. My SplineIK's curve setup

[image: My SplineIK's curve setup]

As you can see, I can't make the curve to shift its bend to the belly like HumanIk, I spent hours changing the CV position but can't mimic how to make the curve bend like HumanIk make the spine bend.

My current setup isn't perfect like HumanIK (100% satisfy), but it's good enough (85% satisfy). But it'd be interesting to figure out how to setup it exactly like HumanIK.

**Edit**: After a month struggling with Maya, I realize I should just use HumanIK. If I want to make my own rig, I should learn from [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MV4XRgmTynY&list=PL8hZ6hQCGHMXKqaX9Og4Ow52jsU_Y5veH) first.

Comment: This is probably not the best place to ask. While 3D is loterated, its your job to demonstrate how it relates to graphic design. Now rigging is a bit out there. Sure you can do this just add a secondary rig to the spline. Anyway in my opinion out of scope for GD.SE

Comment: @joojaa - agree. Hope SE will have a page for Maya/3Ds Max in the future.